# How To Access Session Variables From Seperate Route Files

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am currently using express and express-session to save information. If I save a session variable like this in file '`routes/login.js`'

```
req.session.user = "User1"
```

How do I then access that same variable from '`routes/index.js`' because currently if I just do

```
console.log(req.session.user)
```

it will log undefined but if I do the same thing from inside '`routes/login.js`' it will log "User1"

EDIT:

Inside '`routes/login.js`' file will log "User1"

```
 var express = require('express');
    var redis = require('redis');
    var session = require('express-session');
    var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

    var router = express.Router();
    var client = redis.createClient();

    var store = new RedisStore({host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: client, ttl: 260});

    router.use(session({
         resave: true,
         saveUninitialized: true,
         secret: "secret",
         store: store
        }));

    router.get('/user', function(req, res) {
        req.session.test = "User1";
        res.send(req.session.test); //Logs "User1"
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Inside '`routes/index.js`' file will log undefined

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var config = require('../config/config')

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session); //Logs undefined
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Could you include the code you use to create/register the `express-session` middleware and the relevant routes, i.e. the calls to `app.use` or `app.get` or whatever you're using?

Comment: You only seem to be using the `express-session` middleware within your login router, so requests that don't go through that router won't have a session. Typically you'd register the middleware higher up, so that it's in the chain for all requests that need sessions.

Comment: An alternative to moving it 'higher up' might be to put the relevant code in a separate file and `require` it into every route that needs it.

Comment: When you say relevant code in this scenario would that mean the session middleware and redis store?

Comment: If I use the middleware with the app rather than the router will it be accessible for all routers?

Comment: why dont you use middlewares to write a "before" request hook to  attach user session to each request?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by using the express session middle ware with my app and then accessing it from routes.

Inside app.js

```
app.use(session({
     resave: true,
     saveUninitialized: true,
     secret: "secret",
     store: store
 }));
```

Now I can save a variable to request.session and it will persist through both route files.

Answer (score 0):

> use **`express-session`** in your entry point like **`app.js`** where
>   your app is actually initialized

Before accessing routes in **`app.js`** put the following code

```
app.use(session({
         resave: true,
         saveUninitialized: true,
         secret: "secret",
         store: store
        }));
```

***Remember to maintain the order.***